# cocos2d add a 'ready-go!' animation before the game

Tags: iphone, ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I want to add a 'ready-go!' animation before game, as well as during game (need to pause the game) 
i tried to use `[CCDirector sharedDirector] pushScene: [Anim scene]]`, but although the background of Anim scene is smaller than window size, the transparent area is black instead of see through the scene below.

how can i implement it? (or i don't have to use pushScene at all? )

here is the code for GameScene, onEnter i schedule the 'count' (timer), onExit i unschedule it.

```
-(void) onEnter {
    GameManager* sharedManager = [GameManager sharedManager];
    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] scheduleSelector:@selector(count) forTarget:sharedManager interval:1.0f paused:NO];
    [super onEnter];
}

- (void)onExit {
    GameManager* sharedManager = [GameManager sharedManager];
    [[CCScheduler sharedScheduler] unscheduleSelector:@selector(count) forTarget:sharedManager];
    [super onExit];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem solved. I just create a scene specifically for the 'ready-set-go' animation, pass the necessary parameters to the AnimationScene, then launch the game from the AnimationScene using scheduler. 
The result is not as good as 'ready-go' sign on top of GameScene since i am not able to make the transparent effect, but i tried to mimic the background of game scene, and it turns out quite well.

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)pauseButtonTapped {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];
    [self pauseSchedulerAndActions];
}

- (void)playButtonTapped {
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] resume];
    [self resumeSchedulerAndActions];
}
```

Comment: not what i am asking. i need to make the AnimScene see through. (without hiding the GameScene.

Comment: maybe you need to add it to a layer above the scene and adjust it's alpha, rather than as a new scene

Comment: I need a new Scene because i need to let [CCDirector to pause everything in GameScene.

Comment: CCDirector will pause everything, not just a scene. To pause your 'game scene' make a method that unschedules all of your schedulers that are driving your game tick and logic.

Comment: yeah, of cause i want to pause everything. that all my game logic is on game scene. and timer is not all i schedule.

Answer (score 0):

CCSequence. Before enabling AI timers or whatever runs your game objects, run a CCSequence action.

Comment: too many stuff are scheduled. i hope i can just use ccdirector to pause all of them. but the pushed scene must be transparent.

Comment: If too many things are scheduled can you not move all schedule calls into one method and just call that one method to enable schedules?  Do the same for disabling schedules?

Comment: Nope, the method i want to schedule are from different classes of different module